# how to replace null value for a key in Scala Map

Tags: json, scala, maps, substitution

I have a JSON object of below format:

```
          data:[
                {"id":"1-xyz",
                  "type":"default",
                  "config":{"name":"abc",
                            "isExist":"true",
                            "level":"high"
                            }
                 }
                 ]}
```

In the below code , this JSON object is named as `recordA` and implemented something like:

```
           ......match{
                        case Some(...)=>.......
                        case None=>recordA.copy(status="KO")
                       }
```

What we are doing here is if `case None` , with the existing response , an additional field `status` with value `"KO"` gets added.

Now ,I need to additionally check that if value of `level` is null , I have to set it as `"low"` in the response.

How is this achievable?

Comment: Of course need to indicate which JSON lib

Comment: Its the play_json jar

Comment: Any suggestion here would be very helpful as I am a novice in Scala